# React router dom, component doesn't get unmounted when changing with id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I have a route like this: `<Route exact path="/product/:id" component={Product} />` inside a `Switch`. Inside the component `Product` I have a custom hook that makes a request to my api. I also have another component inside `Product` called: `Configurator`.

Inside the `Configurator` component I make another api request to get a specific choice. Then inside the render of the `Configurator` component I check which component I need to render.

```
{loading ? <Loading /> :
        choices.map((choice, index) => {
            return (
                <div
                    key={choice.id}
                    id={choice?.id}
                    ref={choice?.id == activeChoice ? myRef : empty}
                    className={`${choice?.id == activeChoice ? "active" : "inactive"} configurator__choice`}
                    onClick={() => enableChoice(choice?.id)}
                >
                    {choice?.type === "parent_size" ? <ChoiceSize key={choice.id} number={index + 1} choiceData={choice} availableChoices={availableChoices} activeChoice={activeChoice} onChange={onChange} choices={choices} fetchNewChoiceData={fetchNewChoiceData} onSubmit={onSubmit} /> : <div></div>}
                    {choice?.type === "parent" ? <ChoiceOption key={choice.id} number={index + 1} choiceData={choice} availableChoices={availableChoices} activeChoice={activeChoice} choiceNameId={choice?.id} choiceId={choice?.choices[0]?.next.id} onClick={onClick} /> : <div></div>}
                </div>
            )
        })
}
```

So when `choice.type` is equal to `parent_size it` loads the `ChoiceSize` component and adds data as props.

The problem I have is that whenever I am for example on `/product/1` and I want to switch to `/product/2` my old components (`ChoiceSize` and/or `ChoiceOption`) won't go away. It will add new choices with the data from `product 2` but the old choices from `product 1` are still there.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Maybe that the whole component gets unmounted and the old choices will get removed and the new choices will get added